# Remove item with a specific index using LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Like,

```
List<string> a = {"a0","a1","a2","a3"};
```

Using LINQ, how do I take `a[2]` and remove it?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer at the moment. Provide *real* code rather than pseudo-code for the code you know how to write, and then give more details about what you're trying to achieve. (I doubt that LINQ is the right approach, given that it's for *querying*, but we'll see when you've given more details.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for the [`List.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method instead:

```
a.RemoveAt(2);
```

**Edit**:

> how can i find out it is the before the last index

So you want to remove the second last instead of the one with index 2, you can use the `Count` property to find it. There's absolutely no need to use Linq here:

```
if(a.Count > 1)
    a.RemoveAt(a.Count - 2);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Q9xPgT)

Comment: how can i find out it is the before the last index. using Linq querying

Comment: @karthikeyan: Sorry, what do you need to know?

Comment: Using Linq query a[2] must be found. That is my doubt

Comment: @karthikeyan: What is the problem with the indexer:  `var item = a[2];`?

Comment: Tim sorry, my indexes improve a[3],a[4]... and so on. so, i need to capture the last indexer's predecessor

Comment: @karthikeyan: But you have seen my edit? Do you want to remove the **second** last item?

Answer (score 1):

try this method,

```
 a.RemoveRange(2,1);
```

or

```
 a.RemoveAt(2);
```

Comment: first is used to remove multiple items